# the entire film/book

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

If I say:

"I read the book." or "I watched the film."

**Does it mean** that I read the *entire* book or that I watched the *entire* film?

**If it does**, how should I say to emphasise that I started reading the book or watching the film but haven't finished the *entire* book or film yet?
Will this help: "I was reading the book." "I was watching the film."**?**

**If it doesn't**, how should I say that I read the *entire* book or that I watched the *entire* film?
Will this help: "I've read the book." "I've watched the film."**?**

Thank you for the opportunity to ask questions and get answers.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you're learning English, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) will be a better place for the kinds of questions that learners face.

Comment: "I'm reading the book" will often be understood to mean "I am part way through reading it", even though you are not actually reading at this moment - because we don't usually read a whole book at one sitting. This doesn't apply so much to films, although with modern technology it is of course possible to watch part of a film and save the rest for later.

Comment: It means you watched enough of the film or read enough of the book to make that claim.  You know enough to make conversation on the subject.

Comment: According to your words, if somebody asks me "What did you do yesterday?" I can reply with "I read the books" even though I didn't finish them yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the simple "I read the book" usually implies finishing it. There's enough ambiguity in the usage, though, to enable some intentional duplicity:

> "I know you need to read *To Kill A Mockingbird* for English class. Did you read it today?"
> "Yeah, I read the book."
> "Great, what did you think of the ending?"
> "Wellll.... I *read* the *book*, like, I read *some* of it, but I didn't *finish* it...

This would generally be seen as a misuse. However, you could add a qualifier like a time span that might shift the received meaning to non-completion:

> I read the book for two hours today.
> I might have been bored on the plane, but I read my book.

But no, shifting from simple past to past perfect does nothing to influence a sense of completion, for any task I can think of ("I fixed/have fixed the car," "I cooked/have cooked dinner"), though continuous tenses certainly can ("I'm reading the book").